# Run Junit @Test that ignores @Before/@After

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Is it possible to run a JUnit `@Test` method in a class that has a method annotated with `@Before`, but to ignore the `@Before` method only for this test?

Edit: **I am interested if JUnit supports this functionality**, not workarounds. I am aware of workarounds like moving the test(s) in another class or removing the annotation and manually calling `setUp()` in each test method.

Suppose in a class there are 30 tests, and for 29 of them `@Before` really simplifies the testing initialization, but for one (or more than one) of them is useless/it complicates things.

```
public class MyTestClass {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        //setup logic
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        //[...]
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        //[...]
    }

    //more tests here

    @Test(ignoreBefore = true, ignoreAfter = true //false by default)
    //something equivalent to this
    public void test20() {
        //[...]
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you move `test20` in separate class without `@Before` and `@After` annotation?

Comment: @user1516873 Technically yes, but I would like to keep all the tests for a class in a single test class. When the class was designed/developed, testing was not regarded and refactoring is not a solution either. Also, the definition of unit tests say that they are independent and could be run separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a TestRule. See my answer to [Exclude individual test from 'before' method in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017452/1836). Basically, implement [ExternalResource](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html), and in the apply method, check if there is a specific annotation on the method, and if there is, don't run the before/after method. You'll have to specifically call the before/after from your rule though.

Answer (score 3):

If it useless it should not be a problem - does it harm to run the setUp once more?

However I don't think it's possible and looks for me as a cripple feature.

Another approach - move that test to a separate test-class.

Comment: +1 I'd definitely err on the side of the separate test class. Clearly the other tests have similarities that require them to be grouped together. Your odd-one-out test does not.

Comment: I am actually curious if JUnit offers this functionality, not workarounds. Why would it look like a cripple feature? Isn't in the basic definition of a unit test the idea that unit tests should be fully independent of each other? The other tests shouldn't care if some of them call @Before methods and others don't.

Comment: @m3th0dman this is not dependency between tests, but dependency from test's context. The test is placed in a class with the setUp method. Why is it not executed then? Looks very surprising. Surprises in software development are unpleasant.

Comment: @kan Suppose that you have a class that was not designed for testing, refactoring is not allowed and you want to keep all tests of a production class in a single test class. Anyway, I want a workaround inside JUnit, and I have seen there is.

Answer (score 2):

With JUnit 5 You can have nested tests using @Nested annotation :

```
public class MainClass {
 @Nested
  class InnerClass1 {

  @BeforeEach 
  void setup(){}

  @Test 
  void test1(){}
 }

 @Nested
  class InnerClass2 {
  // No setup

  @Test 
  void test2(){}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, something that I found out on a recent visit to this area.

Junit/Mockito seems to give preference to mocking behavior defined in a test, over a @Before annotated method.