# Run a first test without @Before in JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

In most of my unit-tests on a component with JUnit, I encounter the same issue:
I want to run a first test on the component with no setup to check that it initializes correctly, then I want all my other tests to be done on the component setup in a given way.

I usually end-up with a method that I call at the beginning of all my tests but one, which is ugly and error prone. I could also create two different classes, with one containing only one test, but I don't think that is the most convenient solution.

I tried searching around and found this answer: [Exclude individual test from 'before' method in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017097/exclude-individual-test-from-before-method-in-junit/13017452#13017452), but as far as I could find, the base.evaluate() call will always contain the @Before statement.

Is there a better way to do this first unSetup test?

Comment: Did you try the solution? Did you try the solution with Enclosed? I don't think there are other options.

Comment: I currently use the Enclosed solution, but I like the test code to be the simpler and more readable as possible, and even though it is not terrible, I would like to move the boilerplate out, like a clean annotation could do. The linked solution I hadn't understood before Alexander Zak's answer.

Comment: Why not make the test that's checking initialization act on a different object reference than the other tests, and allow an @Before to construct the object for the other tests? As long as they are constructed the same way, I don't see any problems with this approach.

Comment: That is indeed the most straight forward solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What the answer you linked to meant is that you do not use a @Before annotation at all. Instead you put whatever you wanted to do in the @Before method instead of the

```
// run the before method here
```

comment.

Comment: Indeed, that makes sense. I guess creating a rule taking an Executor running the setup could be reusable and simple.

Comment: You could also create your own @ConditionalBefore annotation and have the rule search for it in the test class